# Identifying family crest?

Tags: surnames, heraldry

This wax seal was in my late grandmother's possession.

Can someone here shed light on the associated surname to this piece?

It doesn't seem to fit her maiden mane (Feild) or her married name (Bergen).

[image]

Comment: Do you have an idea of the possible countries of origin, to narrow things down?

Comment: It's most likely English from my grandmother's side. Otherwise my grandfather's side is Norwegian

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a variation of the Armstrong charge, above a field of wheat?

[image: ARMSTRONG]